# VB.NET Interface Instantiation Oddity

Tags: vb.net, interface, instantiation

I was looking through some legacy code we have and I noticed something that struck me as particularly odd.

Say we have the concrete class `TestClass`.  `TestClass` implements the interface `ITestClass`.

What sort of behavior should I expect in the following case, then?  (I didn't realize this was even possible)

```
Dim testClass as TestClass = Nothing
Try
   testClass = New ITestClass
   ...
End Try
```

As far as I understand, you would be FORCED to utilize `TestClass` instead of its interface counterpart.

Comment: Are you _certain_ `ITestClass` is an interface? Can you post the code for it?

Comment: When I hover over `ITestClass` in Visual Studio, the tooltip says it's an Interface.  When I hover over `TestClass` it says it's a class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's *one* special case, where an interface can be instantiated like a class, and it's related to the [CoClassAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.coclassattribute.aspx). See this blog post for details:

- [Unnatural acts on source code: Instantiating interfaces](http://ayende.com/blog/4121/instantiating-interfaces)

Example from the blog post translated to VB:

```
<ComImport(), Guid("C906C002-B214-40d7-8941-F223868B39A5"), CoClass(GetType(Foo))> _
Public Interface IFoo
End Interface

Public Class Foo
    Implements IFoo
End Class

Sub Main()
    Dim f As New IFoo()    ' Compiles
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow. What a perversion of language features :)

Comment: Wow...I reflected into the DLL and that's exactly what's going on.  That IS weird.

Comment: I've long thought that there should be a concept of a "co-class" paired with an interface; from a *consumer* standpoint, the only difference between interfaces and classes is the fact that interfaces can't have static methods or constructors; to my mind, it would be cleaner not to require there to be any difference.  Can co-classes make static methods available?  Would there be any reasonable pattern for such a co-class making extension methods available on the interface without requiring extra imports?